# Vue: v-for, how loop on property from external class

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a v-for loop with property from an other class (To use it on multiple components)

The html code of Now.vue

```
<tr v-for="(el, index) in rendering.elements" :key="index">
    <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{el.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The Ts of Now.vue

```
    @Component
    export default class Now extends Vue {
        @Prop() private rendering: Render = new Render();

        /**
         * On vue created
         */
        public created () : void
        {
            ApiClient.executeRequest('GET', '/api/stock/state')
                .subscribe((response: any): void => {
                    this.rendering.elements = response.data.result;
                })
        }
    }
```

The rendering.elements is set with the good values but, there aren't update of v-for

This code works:

```
<tr v-for="(el, index) in elements" :key="index">
    <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{el.name}}</td>
</tr>

    @Component
    export default class Now extends Vue {
        @Prop() private elements: Array<any> = [];

        /**
         * On vue created
         */
        public created () : void
        {
            ApiClient.executeRequest('GET', '/api/stock/state')
                .subscribe((response: any): void => {
                    this.elements = response.data.result;
                })
        }
    }
```

Why?

Comment: Is `@Prop` for props? `rendering` should be a `data`. Also, if it doesn't start out with an `elements` member, Vue can't see you add it.

Comment: @RoyJ ok, how can I say to vue 'I added items'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Vue.set`:

```
private rendering: Render = new Render()

public created (): void {
    ...
    Vue.set(this.rendering, 'elements', response.data.result)
    ...
}
```

As @RoyJ mentioned, it's a limitation of Vue's reactivity. The object and its properties must exist on the component, using `set` adds the observable property.